# wp7 xna emulator grid

Tags: xna

hi
is there a grid feature in the xna so i can locate my textures more easily?
do you have other ideas for this problem?
thanks

Comment: Your question does not adequately describe what a "grid feature" actually is. Or what "this problem" is, for that matter. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i meant x and y pixel grid to locate texture and put them in spot without many attempts

Answer (score 1):

You can just draw your own grid. Just draw a 1 pixel image at every 10th coordinate or something. That should do it for you. There is no built in functionality for this, so you're going to have to do it yourself if you really want it.

Edit: I made it sound simple, but really you're going to want to draw the 1 pixel image in a loop similar to:
In your draw() method:

```
for (int x = 1; x < viewPort.Width; ++x) 
{
    for (int y = 1; y < viewPort.Height; ++y)
    {
        if (x % 10 == 0 || y % 10 == 0) 
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(x, y), Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```